# WordPress - отключить плагин для определенных блоков

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Можно ли отключить плагин для определенного div, нашел плагин который отключает выбранные плагины на определенных страницах, но это не то что мне нужно.

```
<header>Хедер</header>
<main>
<h1>заголовок<h1>
<aside>Левый блок</aside>
<div class="gallery">контент</div>
<main>
<footer>футер</footer>
```

Comment: Код ни о чём. Где в нём использование плагина? Какого?

Comment: Налицо [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710).Не плагин нужно отключать, а что-то решать. Вот что решать - с этим создай новый вопрос.

Comment: может быть, задал новый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968322/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это невозможно. Ядро WP при инициализации подключает плагины. На данном этапе можно понять, какая страница будет создаваться. Это обстоятельство использует плагин Plugin Organizer, чтобы отключить ненужные плагины. Но в этот момент совершенно невозможно представить, какие div будут сгенерированы на странице.

Всё, что вы можете сделать - отредактировать шаблон создания страницы и убрать код использования плагина в нужном div.

Comment: "убрать код использования плагина в нужном div."

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Без знания php и WordPress - никак

Comment: Ну знания кое какие есть) Вы подскажите в каком русле рыть или покажите пример

Comment: Без вашего кода сделать это невозможно. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Добавил код, по сути мне нужно чтобы плагин не затрагивал .gallery, или можно даже полностью main

Comment: Или еще как вариант, может так можно - включать плагин только в определенных местах, например вынести эти места в отдельные php файлы (template-part) и только в них включать этот плагин

Comment: Вам надо было править свой вопрос, а не мой ответ)). Перенес ваши дополнения

Comment: `включать плагин только в определенных местах, например вынести эти места в отдельные php файлы (template-part)` - это невозможно, и с этого я начал. Плагины подключает ядро на раннем этапе загрузки.